# How to add a new permission in "node_list_permissions"?

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to  add a new item in `node_list_permissions` function in node module from a custom module. Let me explain my problem.

I have a module say "audit" which will track node history, I have a new tab say history and user whoever have access to see the node history should be allowed to see the history of that node. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To achieve this, you need to create permission.

Following code will create list of permission for all content type.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function HOOK_permission(){
  $permission = array();
  foreach (node_permissions_get_configured_types() as $type) {
    $info = node_type_get_type($type);
    $permission["View history $type content"] =  array(
        'title' => t('%type_name: View content history', array('%type_name' => $info->name)),
    );
  }
  return $permission;
}
```

You need to replace HOOK with your custom module name, and then clear at least "registry" cache.

Then, on permission page you can easily grant permission for each of content type per role.

Hope it will help you.

**Updated answer as per comment**

If I've understand your problem correctly then you want to grant permission to user(s) who have access to see the node revision.

With the above code,I hope you have list of permissions per node for each role.

Now you need to implement hook menu alter .

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function HOOK_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/revisions']['access callback'] = 'your_custom_access';
  $items['node/%node/revisions']['access arguments'] = array(1);
}
```

Here you will alter the 'access callback' argument to check if user has access to see node revision(Don't forget to clear menu cache to see it in action and also make sure that "Create new revision" is checked for the content type).

```
function your_custom_access($node){
  if(user_access("View history $node->type content")){
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Atul, 

Thanks for your replay. What if I want to show this list in node section itself in the permission page(if possible). What will be the access argument in the menu 

<pre>
<code>
$items['node/%node/history'] = array(
    'title' => 'History',
    'page callback' => 'my_callback',
    'access arguments' =>  'WHAT WILL BE HERE',
    'access callback' =>  'WHAT WILL BE HERE'
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 
  );
</code>
</pre>

Comment: @Nabjit, No it is not possible to show custom permissions in node section.

Comment: @NabajitRoy I've updated the answer, please see.

Comment: I am glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A more experienced user should check the below.. I've only added permissions to contrib modules.

From https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7
This will add the permission to the people page.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_permission() {
  return array(
    'see history' => array(
      'title' => t('See History'),
      'description' => t('Blah Blah.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

From 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7
This should check for the permission when viewing that url. I might have gotten the % wrong.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();


  $items['user/%/history'] = array(
    blah
    'access arguments' => array('see history'),
    blah
  );
```